# What can I conclude about "lack of fit"?

Tags: anova

I used a log model and a factor model on 2 parameters colonies and log (dose+1) from R library "salmonella" in the `faraway` library with  18 observations. I need to compare and determine lack of fit. 
The log model produced

```
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)     19.823      5.064   3.915  0.00123 **
log(dose + 1)    2.396      1.128   2.125  0.04955 * 
 an R^2 of 22% with a p-value of .49 which shows a poor fit.
```

Then deviations on x means the results were as follows, how do I interpret the factor results. The coefficients increased and the STD error as well. The $R^2$ was:

```
Multiple R-squared: 0.5475, Adjusted R-squared: 0.359 
F-statistic: 2.904 on 5 and 12 DF,  p-value: 0.0604
```

Then ANOVA of both models, produced

```
Analysis of Variance Table
Model 1: colonies ~ log(dose + 1)
Model 2: colonies ~ factor(log(dose + 1))
  Res.Df    RSS Df     Sum of Sq      F        Pr(>F)
1     16 1881.1                           
2     12 1091.3  4      789.73      2.1709 0.1342
```

**Questions:
how do I interpret these results- the log compared to the factor and then the ANOVA?**

Comment: Using `factor(log(dose + 1))` as an independent variable makes no sense. That would treat log dose as if it was categorical.

Also, you did not run a log model and a factor model (whatever they are) you ran two linear regressions, both with log(dose + 1) as the IV, but one treating it as categorical.

Comment: the data set is from faraway...colonies was the response and log(dose+1)was the predictor as used in the example. Then deviations on x means. Is my factor incorrect for x which is log(dose+1)?

Comment: What do you mean by "then deviations on x means"? 

Turning a numeric variable such as dose into a categorical one (which is what you do by using `factor()`) makes little sense.

Comment: Given that `colonies` is a count variable, you should probably be investigating count regression models such as Poisson or negative binomial.

Comment: maybe I'm using the wrong terminology...in the example, it fits a model that reserves a parameter for each  to declare the predictor to be a factor for each group of data with the same value of x. Using my model: `fit<-lm(colonies~log(dose+1))`?

Comment: Any model that uses `lm()` will be a linear model.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start on how I would approach this data set

```
install.packages('faraway')
library(faraway)
data(salmonella)
with(salmonella, plot(dose, colonies))
with(salmonella, plot(log(dose + 1), colonies))
m1 <- with(salmonella, glm(colonies~dose, family = poisson))
summary(m1)
library(MASS)
m2 <- glm.nb(colonies~dose, data = salmonella)
summary(m2)
```

Comment: so I can use your way to check for lack of fit?

Comment: You can use any method to check for lack of fit; see the help pages for `glm`, or search regarding the methods. If you are really interested in this type of model, a good book on various regression methods is [Long](http://www.amazon.com/Regression-Categorical-Dependent-Quantitative-Techniques/dp/0803973748/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1351527967&sr=8-1&keywords=categorical+and+limited+dependent)

Answer (score 1):

The log model fails the lack of fit test by looking at the ANOVA, Pr(>F) > 0.05. By comparing it to the categorical model, you are basically doing a one way ANOVA (comparing SS_lack.of.fit to SS_pure.error[which is the categorical model]). The R^2 of the categorical model is naturally better because it consumes more degrees of freedom.